# Speed up server response for POSTing JSON to an Express.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

I am trying to POST a base64 string from canvas to an Express.js server, but the console log of the POST/ takes forever and never actually logs the JSON content POSTed.

This is what I use on the client:

```
saveImage: function(e) {
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvasElement');
    var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: base64,
        success: function(e){
            console.log('success', e)
        }
    });
}
```

...then this on the server:

```
var express = require('express'), app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function (request, response) {
  console.log(request.body);
});
```

Comment: Your content type doesn't match your data. base64 is just a plain string of characters, which is not valid JSON.

Comment: I have added this:

var base64String = canvas.toDataURL();
var base64 = JSON.stringify({base64: base64String});

...but still the same, no log on the server.

Comment: You're not using a JSON body parser on the server side (e.g. `body-parser` module with its `bodyParser.json()` middleware).

Comment: Sorry, that is already installed and declared too. I've updated my question to show this now.

Comment: maybe it should be `method: 'POST'` not `type: 'POST'`?

Comment: Still no joy! I can get the server to react by using: $.post('/', {data: "data"}); But then it can console.log the data being sent.